# Value matching with NA - missing values - using mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I am somewhat stuck. Is there a better way than the below to do value matching considering NAs as "real values" within `mutate`?

```r
library(dplyr)

data_foo <- data.frame(A= c(1:2, NA, 4, NA), B = c(1, 3, NA, NA, 4))
```

Not the desired output:

```r
data_foo %>% mutate(irr = A==B)

#>    A  B   irr
#> 1  1  1  TRUE
#> 2  2  3 FALSE
#> 3 NA NA    NA
#> 4  4 NA    NA
#> 5 NA  4    NA

data_foo %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(irr = A%in%B)

#> Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>       A     B irr  
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1     1     1 TRUE 
#> 2     2     3 FALSE
#> 3    NA    NA FALSE
#> 4     4    NA FALSE
#> 5    NA     4 FALSE
```

**Desired output**: The below shows the desired column, `irr`. I am using this somewhat cumbersome helper columns. Is there a shorter way?

```r
data_foo %>% 
  mutate(NA_A = is.na(A), 
         NA_B = is.na(B), 
         irr = if_else(is.na(A)|is.na(B), NA_A == NA_B, A == B))

#>    A  B  NA_A  NA_B   irr
#> 1  1  1 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> 2  2  3 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 3 NA NA  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> 4  4 NA FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> 5 NA  4  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe simpler than [akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56635295/value-matching-with-na-missing-values-using-mutate/56635375#56635375)?
Any of the two ways below will produce the expected result. Note that `as.character` won't do it, because the return value of `as.character(NA)` is `NA_character_`.

```
data_foo %>%
  mutate(irr = paste(A) == paste(B))

data_foo %>%
  mutate(irr = sQuote(A) == sQuote(B))

#Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
#Groups: <by row>
#
## A tibble: 5 x 3
#      A     B irr  
#  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
#1     1     1 TRUE 
#2     2     3 FALSE
#3    NA    NA TRUE 
#4     4    NA FALSE
#5    NA     4 FALSE
```

**Edit.**

1. Following the comments below I have updated the code and it now follows akrun's suggestion.
2. There is also the excellent idea in [tmfmnk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56635295/value-matching-with-na-missing-values-using-mutate/56635635#56635635). I use a similar one in yet another way of solving the question's problem.

The documentation of `all.equal` says that

> Do not use `all.equal` directly in `if` expressions—either use
>   `isTRUE(all.equal(....))` or `identical` if appropriate.

Though there is no `if` expression in `mutate`, I believe that it is more stable than `identical` and has the same effect if the values being compared are (sort of/in fact) equal.

```
data_foo %>%
  mutate(irr = isTRUE(all.equal(A, B)))
```

Comment: Wouldn't `data_foo %>% mutate(irr = paste(A) == paste(B))` works as well.  Please update it in your code otherwise there are people who wants to post that as a solution even if there is a single character difference

Comment: Using `paste`, and @akrun 's improvement, is a very neat and concise suggestion, and easy to understand as well :) Thanks both!

Comment: @akrun Done. And I've also added an extra solution. As it turned out, the last is my favorite one.

Answer (score 6):

Using `map2`

```
library(tidyverse)
data_foo %>%
   mutate(irr = map2_lgl(A, B, `%in%`))
#   A  B   irr
#1  1  1  TRUE
#2  2  3 FALSE
#3 NA NA  TRUE
#4  4 NA FALSE
#5 NA  4 FALSE
```

---

Or with `setequal`

```
data_foo %>% 
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(irr = setequal(A, B))
```

---

The above method is concise, but it is also loopy.  We can replace the NA with a different value and then do the `==`

```
data_foo %>%
     mutate_all(list(new = ~ replace_na(., -999))) %>%
     transmute(A, B, irr = A_new == B_new)
#   A  B   irr
#1  1  1  TRUE
#2  2  3 FALSE
#3 NA NA  TRUE
#4  4 NA FALSE
#5 NA  4 FALSE
```

---

Or with `bind_cols` and `reduce`

```
data_foo %>%
    mutate_all(replace_na, -999) %>% 
    reduce(`==`) %>% 
    bind_cols(data_foo, irr = .)
```

Comment: wow, ok. That's totally above my level ... as often with your answers! Big fan of your concise code :) Thanks

Comment: @Tjebo It's okay.  Rui's answer is better

Answer (score 2):

Could also be a possibility:

```
data_foo %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(irr = identical(A, B)) %>%
 ungroup()

      A     B irr  
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1     1     1 TRUE 
2     2     3 FALSE
3    NA    NA TRUE 
4     4    NA FALSE
5    NA     4 FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

The coalesce function is useful if you want to perform an action when a value is NA

```
data_foo %>% 
  mutate(irr = coalesce(A == B, is.na(A) & is.na(B)))

#    A  B   irr
# 1  1  1  TRUE
# 2  2  3 FALSE
# 3 NA NA  TRUE
# 4  4 NA FALSE
# 5 NA  4 FALSE
```

Same thing for > 2 columns

```
data_foo %>% 
  mutate(irr = coalesce(reduce(., `==`), rowMeans(is.na(.)) == 1))
```