# Efficient way to check for inequality between two columns accounting for NAs in R?

Tags: r, filter, inequality

When I filter to check for inequality between two columns, I need to be explicit about NAs in the data, because filter keeps rows where the condition evaluates to TRUE, and NAs sort of break that evaluation. Here is what I mean:

Take the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:4,NA,6:10), y = c(1,2,NA,3,6,NA,7,8,9,11))
df
    x  y
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3 NA
4   4  3
5  NA  6
6   6 NA
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
10 10 11
```

When I want to know which rows are unequal, the following code doesn't cut it:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(x != y)

   x  y
1  4  3
2 10 11
```

Instead, I need to be explicit about NAs:

```
df %>% filter(x != y | (is.na(x) & !is.na(y)) | (!is.na(x) & is.na(y)))

   x  y
1  3 NA
2  4  3
3 NA  6
4  6 NA
5 10 11
```

...but that is just too verbose. I tried with other methods, like base subsetting and `subset`, but this inconvenience persists.

So, is there a more straightforward way to check for inequality accounting for NAs??

Comment: How do you intend to account for NAs? Is NA == NA? You cannot check if 3 == NA because you cannot know if 3 is equal to "I don't know". It would help if you clearly stated what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Other related suggestions/approaches may be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56635295/value-matching-with-na-missing-values-using-mutate/56635375#56635375

Comment: @Conor yes yes, I know I know... just trying to do what I'm asking for. If you really need to know, I'm trying to get to the same results from another report and make a subsetting where we got different results.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. What is your expected result for 3 == NA and NA == NA?

Comment: TRUE and FALSE, respectively. As the first one is indeed unequal, and the second one is equal.

Comment: OK, so if you want NA != NA to return FALSE then you should go for the solution presented by G. Grothendieck. Mine would return TRUE in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format them first:

```
df %>% filter(format(x) != format(y))
```

giving:

```
   x  y
1  3 NA
2  4  3
3 NA  6
4  6 NA
5 10 11
```

Comment: `format(NA)` is the character string "NA" and that does not equal, for example, the character string "3".

Comment: I see, so it would be the same as `paste(x) != paste(y)`... interesting approach!

Answer (score 1):

Using base R you can do this:

```
df[(df$x!=df$y | is.na(df$x!=df$y)),]
#        x  y
#    3   3 NA
#    4   4  3
#    5  NA  6
#    6   6 NA
#    10 10 11
```

It is necessary to explicitly include the comparisons that yield NA by using `is.na()`

Comment: Thanks! I see now that using dplyr I can do `df %>% filter(x != y | is.na(x != y))`, which is shorter (which is what I'm looking for!)